# Problems with under extrusion and clogs on CR-10

Tags: nozzle, creality-cr-10, underextrusion

I've asked a question before on the extruder gear clicking on my CR-10, but I'm certain its because of the nozzle getting clogged for some reason. I'm using a standard 0.4 mm nozzle with white PLA and randomly during the print the extruder gear starts clicking on the fast parts and then under extrudes the rest of the print, eventually the hobbed gear digs away at the filament and doesn't grip anymore. Why would the nozzle keep getting clogged? Could it be because the filament isn't high enough quality and is leaving particles in the nozzle?

[image]

Additionally, when I performed a cold pull after breaking up the blockage on the inside, the filament came out like a thin film even though it was purging fine before I cooled it down. Why?

[image]

- 190 °C nozzle temperature (tried printing at 210 °C and the filament burned)
- 50 °C bed temperature
- 60 mm/s speed, outline 50 % - first layer being 30 mm/s
- 0.2 mm layer height

This starting happening after I returned to printing after a 6 month break, with the filament being stored in a cool and dry cupboard for around a year (the filament was on the cheaper side, but still highly recommended by SUNLU)

Comment: Why did you edit it? It was perfectly understandable before. I figured out the problem anyway, I printed with a higher quality sample filament I had and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Hi and welcome to 3D Printing.SE. At SE sites we need clear and well formatted questions, please take the [tour] and acquaint yourself using [help]. Great you put in a solution as an answer!

Comment: we strive to use the scientific notation, including the mandatory fixed-space between number and unit.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the filament was the problem, I tried printing a model with a high quality sample PLA filament I had and it printed perfectly; one of the cleanest prints I've had. Never skimp on filament.

[image]

Comment: That looks like a fine print, glad you solved it with new filament!

Answer (score 0):

White PLA is usually some of the worst stuff to print with, generally avoid it. I would say. I myself are having a lot of problems with it as well.

Comment: I've printed a lot in white PLA which does not have the problems like you mention. To say that that is usually a general problem is a bold statement.

Comment: @0scar The colorant that is typically used for making the filament white has a negative impact on print quality, clogging the extrusion and so on. But with the right settings, you can sometimes fix it. Typically raising the temperature can levitate it. Share your brand of white pla, would like to try it.

Comment: If the pigment is the problem, then it would be a problem with other filaments as well (PETG, ABS, ...), or would that be mitigated by the temperature? Can you share a source for this, I'm curious to read about it. It also should be added to the answer to prevent discussion in the comments. My filament brand is ColorFabb.